# IValueConverter maintain state if cannot set converter parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a IValueConverter which converts an enum value to a localised string via a lookup table, and vice versa. To find the correct table it first needs to know the name of the table. When the enum value is passed into the converter via the Convert method it is possible to find this. When the string is passed into the converter via the ConvertBack method it isn't (enum types are unique, but the string values are not).

The converter is used on DataTemplates for editors used in a Data Grid and a Property Grid.

In one case it is possible to pass the name of the table in as the ConverterParameter, as the DataTemplate is dynamically generated. In the other it does not seem possible to do this. My current solution looks up the table name in the Convert method and stores it for use in the ConvertBack method (i.e. the IValueConverter maintains state between calls to Convert and ConvertBack). This assumes that Convert will always be called before ConvertBack, which does not seem like a safe assumption. I'm using a per binding instance of the converter:

```
<converters:EnumToStringConverter x:Key="EnumToStringConverter" x:Shared="False"/>
```

Is this safe or will this come back to haunt me? The converter methods look like this:

```
private string listName = null;

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (parameter == null)
    {
        parameter = ListManager.FindListNameFromObject(value);
    }
    listName = (string)parameter;
    return ListManager.GetKeyFromValue((string)parameter, value);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

    if (parameter == null)
    {
        parameter = listName;
    }
    return ListManager.GetValueFromKey((string)parameter, (string)value);
}
```

An alternative I've been trying to see if is possible, is to create a dependency property on the converter, and bind this to the name of the collection somehow. Is there a way to set the DataContext of the converter to be the same as the binding it is acting on? Currently the converter is a StaticResource so has no DataContext.

Thanks

Comment: I am still not sure of your question. Whats the issue really?

Comment: The converter needs some extra information to be able to work. This can be found in the Convert method, but not the ConvertBack. It is not possible to bind to the ConverterParameter so that doesn't work. IMultiValueConverter has the same problem: the extra data could be bound as input to Convert but not the ConvertBack. So are there any other ways of getting this extra information into a Converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Converters` are not allowed to be `DependencyObject`s in WPF as they wouldnt be able to provide biding to their properties which could change dynamically.

Code below converts a `Key` to `Value` & `Value` to `Key` using dynamically bound `Dictionary`.

**XAML**

```
 <StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <FrameworkElement x:key="ProxyElement" 
                        DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" 
                   DataContext="{Binding MyDictionary}"
                   Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Key, 
                           Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                           ConverterParameter={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     object Convert(value, parameter ..)
     {
          var dict 
              = ((FrameworkElement)parameter).DataContext 
                  as Dictionary<string, string>)parameter;
          return (dict[value.ToString()];
     }

     object ConvertBack (value, parameter ..)
     {
        var dict 
              = ((FrameworkElement)parameter).DataContext 
                  as Dictionary<string, string>)parameter;

        foreach(var item in dict)
        {
            if (item.Value == value)
            {
                return item.Key;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Fantastic, this solves it nicely. Out of interest, why is the ContentControl needed? It seems the DataContext of the FrameworkElement isn't set without it, but the DataContext of the ContentControl is not required so this works: <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}" />

Comment: I set the `Dictionary` as dataContext of the `ContentControl`. If you dont set that then the entire `ViewModel` would be available as `DataContext` of the `ProxyElement`. So it depends on how you extract the `Dictionary` in the converter. Consider this... in case of entire `ViewModel` based extraction, the `Converter`'s assembly has to refer the `ViewModel`'s assembly. But what if the `Converter` is in a generic or common library (which does not refer specific `ViewModel`s)?

Comment: Really nice solution!  Just for those not so familiar with WPF and to save you time `x:Key` should have a capital K..

Comment: @ajphall you can edit the answer and correct it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could always Bind your value to just "." this would then give you your DataContext in the converter then you could persist the state in that object instead.

Comment: I thought this might solve it, but unfortunately it is not possible to ConvertBack to the data context this way.

Comment: It's the same issue: In the Convert method having the data context gives you access to the list of localised strings. In the ConvertBack method you just have the string, and no other data, which is the same problem as if binding to the Enum value.

Comment: @james this extra data you need in the convertback method, is that not available in your data context? when the ConvertBack is run, whats the object type of Value?

Comment: Yes it is available in the data context. For some reason if I change the binding to the data context the convert back method isn't called (possibly it is read only), but even if it was, the type of the value parameter in the convert back method is the same as the type returned by the convert method (in this case a string) so the data context isn't available.

Comment: This method won't work because binding to some element which hosts the DataContext means the binding won't respond to property changes in the bound value.